# Android In App Purchase Signature Validation

Tags: c#, android, validation, security, in-app-purchase

I am using Xamarin.Android and use the [BillingClient](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingClient) for In App Purchases. I use the following code to successfully verify the originalJson signature of a purchase:

```
private bool ClientSignatureValid(string originalJson, string signature, string key)
{
    var success = false;

    try
    {

        var decodedSignature = Android.Util.Base64.Decode(signature, 0);
        var decodedData = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(originalJson);
        var decodedPublicKey = Android.Util.Base64.Decode(key, 0);
        
        var keyFactory = Java.Security.KeyFactory.GetInstance("RSA");
        var sign = Signature.GetInstance("SHA1withRSA");

        var keySpec = new Java.Security.Spec.X509EncodedKeySpec(decodedPublicKey);
        var key = keyFactory.GeneratePublic(keySpec);

        sign.InitVerify(key);
        sign.Update(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(originalJson));

        success = sign.Verify(decodedSignature);

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        logger?.LogInformation($"Failed to verify android purchase data: {e.Message}");
    }

    return success;
}
```

I want to implement the same signature validation on my server and don't have access to the same java packages to reuse the same code. I have tried converting to use System.Security.Cryptography but the code always fails to validate the signature.

The code looks like this:

```
public bool ServerSignatureValid(string originalJson, string signature, string key)
{
    var success = false;

    try
    {
        var decodedSignature = System.Convert.FromBase64String(signature);
        var decodedData = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(originalJson);
        var decodedPublicKey = System.Convert.FromBase64String(key);

        var rsa = System.Security.Cryptography.RSA.Create();
        rsa.ImportSubjectPublicKeyInfo(decodedPublicKey, out _);

        success = rsa.VerifyData(
            decodedData,
            decodedSignature,
            System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithmName.SHA1,
            System.Security.Cryptography.RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        logger?.LogInformation($"Failed to verify android signature data: {e.Message}");
    }

    return success;
}
```

The only definition from Google that I can find is [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/Purchase#getSignature()) and only goes as far as specifying the RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 scheme.

The parameters looks something like this:

```
string key = @"MIIBIjANBgkq...";
string originalJson = "{\"productId\":\"uk.co...\"";
string signature = "LQC7ps7Db577I8Iq...";
```

I have tried various combinations and can't seem to get the validation to pass on the Server. What have I done wrong?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was using the wrong key, it was for a different app. The code is fine.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Answers (and questions) should be written such that future users can learn from them, too. Please either [edit] this answer to provide details about what was wrong, or consider deleting your question entirely (I think you'll have to delete this answer first).